# Horizontally center object inside parallelogram

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I currently have parallelogram that was created with a `div` and the css property `clip-path`. This shape is stake to the stop and bottom of the screen with a dynamic width as well. I'm trying to figure out how to horizontally (not vertically) center the content.

My issue is that any text that I try to center seems to center to the rectangle, not the parallelogram that I have created.

So far I've tried to use left and right padding, percentage based margins, and clip paths of the content within the `div` to no avail.

I've attached [a codepen](https://codepen.io/oneGregWiley/pen/WNvPGZq) with where I'm at so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue lies in the fact that your parallelogram isn't actually parallel to the rectangle. Change it to `polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);`, then adjust margins appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

> text-algin-center;

to your 
 **.sidebar-callout-padding** and

> display:inline-block;

to your paragraphs (give them an unique ID)

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
#yourdiv {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="yourdiv">Your text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for a square container, but I need to adjust for the inset created by a parallelogram.